# ER_PARSE_ERROR at MySql Object in Node

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, backend, mysql-error-1064

I am trying to insert `phone number` and `name` of respective person,

and then I am trying retrive the inserted record,
Here is my code ....

> phone number contains Country Code:
> Ex: +911234567890

```
app.get('/insertAndGetUser',(req,res) => {
    console.log('insertAndGetUser method Called => ');
    let name = req.query.username;
    let phone = `+${req.query.number}`;
    con.query(`insert into user(name,phone) values('${name}','${phone}'`,(err,results,fields) => {
        if(err) throw err;
        con.query(`select * from user where phone=${phone}`,(err,results,fields) => {
            if(err) throw err;
            console.log('Response');
            let userObj = results;
            console.log(userObj[0]);
            res.send(userObj[0]);
        })
    })
})
```

but it throws the following error ...

```
  code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR',
  errno: 1064,
  sqlMessage: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1",
  sqlState: '42000',
  index: 0,
  sql: "insert into user(name,phone) values('Nagaraj',' 91xxxxxxxxxx'"
```

from the above we can see `+` symbol is not displaying...  :(
I don't know the actual error?....

Comment: You open two parenthesis and close one. Also, I can spot SQL injection at its best. Your query should look like `insert into user(name,phone) values(?, ?)`; check you framework documentation for the details.

Comment: Actually.. you could just add `` these around the fields, eg: ```user(`name`, `phone`)``` and it'll work just fine. This is MySQL syntax btw. Also, be careful with numbers in a query, cuz you have to pass it **AS A NUMBER**, so I'm guessing this is invalid ```'${phone}'```

Answer (score 1):

you need to allow multiple statements in your mysql connection

```
const db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "",
    database: "users",
 
    multipleStatements: true })
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using string literals,,

I am suppose to use Placeholder `?` in sql Statement..

> con.query(`insert into user(name,phone) values(?,?)`,[name,phone],(err,results,fields) => { doSomething....}

Answer (score 0):

Balance your parentheses.

Remove the SQL injection vulnerability. Because cybercreeps.

And, phone numbers can be weird in js, because they sometimes look like numbers.

Instead of

```
let phone = `+${req.query.number}`
```

try

```
let phone = '+' + req.query.number.toString()
```

and see if you get better results.

Comment: it prints the number with space ex: `+ 91xxxxxxxxxx' not '+91xxxxxxxxxx' and throws error

Comment: It looks like your `req.query.number` value contains a leading space.

Comment: NO it is like '+91xxxxxxxxxx'